# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android

I'm just starting with programming Android apps and was working through the developers guide on android.com. When trying to display a text on a second `activity` it says it cannot resolve the symbol `EXTRA_MESSAGE` as you can see here:

[image: second activity]

[image: main activity]

As far as I can tell I did every step like the guide says. I also tried copy and pasting everything but it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Post the actual code.

Comment: In your SecondActivity use `android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE` instead of `MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE`. But I suggest you to define class variable as said Gabe Sechan in his post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a static import of extra message from some random class in MainActivity.  That's wrong, don't do that.  Define EXTRA_MESSAGE as a public final static String, with whatever value you want (I'd suggest "message") in your MainActivity.

Comment: That's what I missed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways of solving it.

1) Use same static variable (Its a dirty way). At `DisplayMessageActivity` use `android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE`.

2) This approach I recommend you. Create public static final String field at `MainActivity`, remove `android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE`, and use `MainAcitivity` field at both classes. Content of this variable does not matter as long as it is unique extra key.